# view.postUrl() Not sending $_POST values

Tags: php, android, android-webview, session-variables

I have a routine that logs a user onto our web site, the login program returns the session id and stores it in the Shared Preferences, so it can be used in subsequent php programs on the site. I've also looked at the related type questions here on the board which is how I found the postUrl.

We use an Android Webview to display the remaining pages (all php), so i'm trying to pass the saved session id back to the next php page.

```
      postData="sid="+SessionId;
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Post Data Is "+postData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The Toast displays the correct information. I then send it to the php file

```
               view.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "UTF=8"));
```

It goes to the correct php file, but it seems like nothing is really going, in the php file i have this to test for success

```
    $what_is_session=strip_tags(trim($_POST['sid']));
    echo "What Is Session Id = ".$what_is_session;
```

$what_is_session is always blank. Not sure where else to look, things seem to be in the proper place and have values when the app calls the webview and the php program.
TIA

Comment: ALso use isset() first to see if data comes in.

Comment: `$what_is_session=strip_tags(trim($_POST['sid']));`. You should of course have there: `$what_is_session=$_POST['sid'];`. Or better yet: `$sid=$_POST['sid'];`

Comment: greenapps - I tried the straight $_POST[] early on and I just tried "$sid=$_POST['sid']" and isset() returns not set.

Comment: Well if isset() is false then the php script has not received that parameter. Now take your conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.  The solution was to use $_GET instead of $_POST and to build the Url as a complete string and then use `view.loadUrl(url);` Session Id was sent.

Comment: That is not a solution. You wanted to post.

Comment: greenapps,  yes it is, the ultimate goal was to get the Session ID over, and that was accomplished. and your suggestions didn't work.